# How do I exit Vim?

Tags: code-golf

Vim is a great text editor for unix systems, but it's notorious for being difficult to exit.

Write a full program that will output `:q` to exit Vim. It should then read a single line of input, as it will then either be given a bash prompt, in which case the exit was successful, or an error, in which case there are unsaved changes.

The bash prompt will be this:

```
E37@vimmachine: /var/override)
```

While the error will be this:

```
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

Upon being given the bash prompt, the program's work is done, and it should not give any more output (except for whitespace).

Upon being given the error, your program should randomly (ie each possibility has a non-zero probability of being chosen) output `:q!`, to exit without saving, or `:x`, to save and exit.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins!

Comment: I didn't know `:x` was a thing! I've always used `:wq` :)

Comment: What if my bash prompt is `E37: No write since last change`? That is, how can an algorithm distinguish a prompt from an error message?

Comment: @anatolyg it can't, but it also doesn't have to. The given prompt will always be the one above, that is `E37@vimmachine: /var/override)`

Comment: @Mayube Should there be a newline between `':q'` and `':q!'`, or are we allowed to eliminate this?

Comment: @musicman523 nowhere in the spec does it say anything about requiring any newlines ;)

Comment: Can I use command-line args for the input line?

Comment: Why does the prompt end with a `)`?

Comment: *The given prompt will always be the one above* That should be stated in the challenge spec. As is, it says *looks like this*, which can mean any number of things.

Comment: This reminded me of the [SO Blog Entry: Stack Overflow: Helping One Million Developers Exit Vim](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/)

Comment: Proposing to migrate to askubuntu! Probably it will get there even higher response '^.^

Comment: (joined golf for this comment, sheesh) @musicman523 NEVER use `:x` to exit vim. Someday you'll accidentally hit `:X` then random keys when you're confused. After you finally `:wq` you'll never see your file again.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin Welcome to PPCG! Let's continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: @AaronMcMillin I always `save-and-exit` with `:x` and I've never had a problem

Comment: @musicman523 I find that ZZ is by far the easiest way to save and exit vim.

Comment: Personally, I would do `Ctrl+Z` followed by `kill -9 %%`

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder and 4 thanks to @Mayube!

```python
from random import*
if'('in input(':q'):print choice([':x',':q!'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDsIwDEV3TuFOSREsMCBFYmTlAoBQlLjUErWDGygcnDmETu8//Zc@uRfeFOL0zLAH9dN13qVTGapyrKAhieblgjpjDTHMhTXucWbTuqTEGUIvFNCejHubVb0ac2lLOWx3Do4Ck1JGGIkDwt2P/9zzDcH6GKGBLCAvVKWI7ZdlHXzo8Qc)

Comment: If you switch to Python 2, you can save 1 bytes by using `print ` instead of `print()`. And you can take the input with quotes

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks, it actually saved me 3 bytes!

Comment: Yes, I didn't see you had 2 print statements

Comment: I gave this tip to totallyhuman so it's only fair I give it to you as well. You can remove `print':q'` altogether and change `input()` to `input(':q')`

Comment: @Mayube oh that's awesome, thank you!

Comment: the `\n` isn't necessary, the spec doesn't require a trailing newline

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 35 bytes

```rb
p:q
p %i(q! x)[rand 2]if/\(/=~gets
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8CqkKtAQTVTo1BRoUIzuigxL0XBKDYzTT9GQ9@2Lj21pPj/f1djcysFv3yF8qLMklSF4sy85FSFnMTiEoXkjMS89FQFjcSUFAVFhZJ8hfyy1KKizJRUza95@brJickZqQA)

Comment: You can shave a byte by removing the space between `p` and `:q` ;)

Comment: awesome and weird! I didn't know that, thanks @ymbirtt

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
„:q,'Nåi„:x…:q!‚.R,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcM8q0Iddb/DSzNBzIpHDcusChUfNczSC9L5/9/V2NxKwS9fobwosyRVoTgzLzlVISexuEQhOSMxLz1VQSMxJUVBUaEkXyG/LLWoKDMlVfNrXr5ucmJyRioA)

```
„:q,                # Print the string ":q"
    'Nåi            # If N is in the input
        „:x         #   Push the string ":x"
           …:q!     #   Push the string ":q!"
               ‚    #   Wrap them into an array
                .R, #   Randomly print one of them
```

Answer (score 6):

## Vimscript, <strike>45</strike> 41 bytes

```
ec"q"|exe"/("|ec["q!","x"][getpid()%2]
```

Shaved off 4 bytes by using `getpid()` to get a number. (Can anyone think of a shorter way to get a number that won't be the same everywhere, all the time?)

Assuming +3 bytes for invoking Vim with `-c` to run the above script and `-` to read input from stdin:

```
vim -c 'ec"q"|exe"/("|ec["q!","x"][reltime()[1]%2]' -
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>76</s> <s>75</s> <s>72</s> 69 bytes

**This answer has been [out-golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127479).**

*-1 byte thanks to Rod. -3 bytes thanks to Mayube. -3 bytes thanks to Artyer.*

```python
from random import*
print'::qx!'[random()>.5:('N'in input(':q'))*5:2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jck7DsIwDADQnVO4k5NKMBRVSBnYuvYCiCFKAo1E7dQ1v4MzBySmN7zy1ompq/UiPIN4ij/yXFi03RTJpOjc8mrw9D9jj7veGRwxE2QqdzXoFrS27V13rhWH/cHByPCUrAnWTCHBza8KYfJ0TWB8jNCAMvAjieSYLH6It8GHKX0B)

Comment: This prints an extra newline where the challenge says `it should not give any more output`

Comment: `@Mayube May we output a newline upon terminating?` `@Adám sure, that's fine`

Comment: `random()>.5` to save a byte

Comment: `print'::qx!'[random()>.5:('N'in input(':q'))*5:2]` saves three bytes

Comment: Ohh, that's clever. Thanks!

Comment: Does the randomness have to be uniformly distributed? If not, you could do `random()>0`, because there is a very *very* small chance that `random()` will return `0`.

Comment: @Artyer You know what `[0, 1)` means, right? It means that zero is *included* because the range is zero-inclusive. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396303/2415524 ...The easy way to remember it is that on a number line, closed dots are included, and open dots aren't. Brackets look closed, and parens look open.

Comment: @mbomb007 Huh. My mistake.

Comment: I have a 47 byte answer if we don't need uniform randomness.

Comment: @mbomb007 You don't need uniform randomness according to the challenge spec: `each possibility has a non-zero probability of being chosen`.

Comment: @mbomb007 Your suggestion of `random()>0` brings about an interesting question. In mathematics, the probability of choosing any discrete quantity in a continuous range is `0` because, although it could at some point be chosen, there are an infinite number of such numbers, so the probability of each of them being chosen must be 0.

Comment: However in computer science, the representation format for floating point numbers is _not_ infinite, meaning the range `[0,1)` is actually a discrete quantity. According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2978945/8028578), a number using IEEE754 format can represent `1023*2^52` numbers in the range `[0,1)`, which means the probability of selecting `0` is `1/(1023*2^52)`. This is also discussed in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450688/why-isnt-math-random-outputting-0-ever).

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>140 139</strike> 138 bytes

```cs
using static System.Console;class P{static void Main(){Write(":q");if(ReadLine()[3]==':')Write(new System.Random().Next()>9?":x":":q!");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcyxCsIwEIDhV4lZehns4mRKdXBVkTo4iENITzloL9iLWil99lhQ5//n8zL3ocOUHkJ8UxJdJK@Ob4nY5pvAEhosfONE1GH41WegWu0cMZjh1FFE0PauTUFXqNDVW2IEc15cyjKzmfkejK@/WjmuQwsm32MfwayWa217bSdjNiHjmNIH)

- 1 byte saved thanks to LiefdeWen!
- 1 byte saved thanks to Mord Zuber!

Comment: Placing your program in the `System` namespace makes you able to shorten `System.Random` to `Random`, saving 1 byte

Comment: @CarlosAlejo works for me in TIO, however it outputs `q!` not `:q!`

Comment: I don't see that they say a newline is needed after final output so cant you change `C.WriteLine` to `C.Write`?

Comment: @LiefdeWen `namespace System` is longer than what I saved by removing `System.`. About the newline, yes, I was considering removing that, thank you!

Comment: @Mayube oops, I slipped my fingers on the keyboard. I fixed it and removed the newlines after the commands, if that's OK.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Ahh, I didn't even realize that you didn't use a namespace, the question also doesn't say uniformly random, just all possibilities should have non-zero chance so you change `.Next(2)>0` to `.Next()>9`, it leaves a bit of a bad taste in the mouth but it's still legal.

Comment: `using static System.Console` lets you drop all `C.` calls, and saves you a byte

Comment: @MordZuber what the...? I didn't even know that was possible! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

- Had a redundant `!o`.
- -1 byte thanks to Aaron.

```
iii0["@!qx:q:"ooi{=?;o!ox~oo;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcLNCkBAFAbQV/nGirWFGomNrXeYzMUtzW1@QimvPqRzFo5bzsWg/KW9LkT4@d1d34r6XI9Im/NYNxqT4AycCJHdTNhNTJg341ZCaayFQhLIQSGwpeoF)

### Explanation (old)

```
"@!qx:q:"ooi~i~i~i{=?;o!ox~oo;
"@!qx:q:"                        Push @!qx:q: on the stack (in reverse)
         oo                      Print :q [stack: @!qx:]
           i~i~i~                Remove first 3 input characters
                 i               Load @ or : from the input (= i)
                  {              Shift stack to the left [stack: !qx:i@]
                   =?            If 4th character was @
                     ;              Exit
                                 Else
                      o             Print :
                       !o           Jump to
                         x          Random direction (left or right because
                                    up and down retrigger x)
                                       Left:
                     ;o!o                 Print x and exit.
                                       Right:
                          ~oo;            Remove x, print q! and exit.
```

(will update soon)

Comment: I'm not sure this would be allowed, but you could win one byte by reading the 3 characters to discard first, then start working on a new stack with `[` : `iii0[` wil leave you with an empty stack ; nice one anyway, I like how you populate all your possible outputs at the start to avoid additional quotes

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, that's a very neat trick! Why wouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: Because you'd be reading the input before having printed the output that leads to its production, which I suppose goes against the spirit of the challenge. However it's not like the challenge can realistically implemented with the official ><> interpreter since python will wait for the input's EOF before executing the ><> code (or something like that)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, <s>52</s> 46 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @ETHProductions*

```
prompt(':q')[30]&&alert(new Date%2?':q!':':x')
```

Comment: Doesn't there need to be a `!` after the `:q` if the input is an error?

Comment: @Shaggy aww, didn't notice that, there goes 9 bytes

Comment: I think you can save a few bytes with `prompt(':q')[30]&&...`. Also, `new Date%2?':x':':q!'`

Comment: @ETHproductions oh yeah, thanks! not sure how I overlooked a ternary

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 27 bytes

```
":q"ü[":x",":q!"]`⌂`J'!,cIƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/1/JqlDp8J5oJasKJR0gW1EpNuFRT1OCl7qikquxuZWCX75CeVFmSapCcWZecqpCTmJxiUJyRmJeeqqCRmJKioKiQkm@Qn5ZalFRZkqqplKy57FJ//9/zcvXTU5MzkgFAA) (Note: As TIO doesn't play nice with stdin, I've replaced the `,` (read from stdin) with the literal string, which you can change to test it. Also, you'll need to disable output cache in order to get a different response with the random output.)

Explanation:

```
":q"ü[":x",":q!"]`⌂`J'!,cIƒ
":q"ü                       - Push the literal :q and print
     [":x",":q!"]           - Push the list of literals :x and :q!
                 `⌂`J       - Push function literals ⌂ (terminate) and J (choose random element from list)
                     '!     - Push the literal !
                       ,    - Read from stdin
                        c   - Pop top two values a,b and return "a".count(b)
                         I  - Pop top three values a,b,c and return b if a is truthy and c if a is falsy
                          ƒ - Pop a function from the stack and call it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 27 bytes

```apl
':q'⋄('!'∊⍞)/':q!' ':x'⊃⍨?2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY09bsJAEIV7n2JcDRTI/BRI25DGRSREJMQFRt4RrGTvkmVlCC1RQCBHaVImNeeaO1AbB6J0eeXT975Hy7yjXyh381reP6djefvoglRf4MlqV5gtw@zxKZLDPt2YUKN6Rjm9tjBGORyl@m4nTRUjoNqgHHdSnUf9uqFruAV7qwAUAhfLoDC6lz@mKB0MH0pTFJQtjGUFSUk@cSV7bzS3f0nsW/3vXMHEwdqbwLAyNmPIqTnLFmTnDC3SGmIIDv6cF@s6WXPHVw)

`':q'` print this

`⋄` then

`?2` random integer among the first two

`⊃⍨` use that to select from

`':q!' ':x'` this list of two strings

`(`…`)/` replicate that with, i.e. make *n* copies of each element in that, where *n* is

`'!'∊⍞` is exclamation point a member of the text input? (Boolean, i.e. 0 or 1)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>76</s> <s>71</s> 50 bytes

```js
prompt(":q")[3]<"@"?alert(new Date%2?":q!":":x"):0
```

Saved a bunch of bytes thanks to Artyer and Neil, as well as condensing my ternaries and moving first alert to prompt (duh).

Comment: Why not just call `prompt()` directly? (Also, are you allowed `prompt(":q")`?)

Comment: You can use the time as a random number (`new Date%2` instead of `Math.random()>.5`), and you can use prompt directly like @Neil said: `prompt()[3]<`

Comment: @Neil Why? I had been doing a `.indexOf` on it, before I noticed the other way to do it. Forgot to switch back, thanks!

Comment: @Artyer thanks, I had thought of that and then forgot about it

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 98 bytes

```
@echo :q
@set/ps=
@if %s:~3,1%==@ exit/b
@set/an=%random%%%2
@if %n%==0 (echo :x)else echo :q!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes (32 code, +1 for -n flag)

```ruby
p:q;$_[?!]? p([:q!,:x][$$%2]): p
```

I'm not too sure on the `$$%2` snippet. I'm using it to generate a random bit to index my array by taking the current ruby process's pid modulo 2, and it'll be fairly unpredictable. `.sample` adds an extra byte.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8Cq0FolPtpeMdZeoUAj2qpQUceqIlavODG3ICdV00qh4P9/xX/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
import time
if'w'in input(':q'):print'::qx!'[time.time()%2>1::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsIwFAX3nuJ1IUk3gnEhfNBdt15AREIT7QebpOnX6Okj7WYYmEk/GWIwlUN6C07IttxXrzymmAXCo9/wQxXFAWvRiibVUsocRBFN30Zdl2u3QLdbc94TmVut3eFIuESUzOIxc@g9XnYW9IMNTw9tnUMDiYgfnzM73/4B)

Since this is just an agglomeration of [both](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127479/48878) of [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127480/48878) Python answers, I've marked this as community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
print'::qx!'[id(0)%3<2:('N'in input(':q'))*5:2]
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##BcHNCsIwDADgV8kOklYQpEOE4HXXvYB4KG2wAUm3Lv49uOf6fcvXStXQ@9JEDYnWz4BXye7od@MlkMMZRUF0eZpDWtH7/YnCrXecxjPBXOHdxBg20cTwiJtBKlHvDC7mDANYhfri1iSzx5/WQ4qp8B8)

**Explanation:**

The source of randomness is `id(0)%3<2`. The function `id` returns the memory location of the parameter. Passing anything will give a non-deterministic memory address. The result will always be even, but it will only sometimes be divisible by 3. The results modulo 3 vary. So, this can be a source of randomness. Using `<2` means that roughly 2/3 of the time, the resulting boolean is `True`.

The rest of the answer is inspired by [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127480/34718).

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), <del>14</del> 12 bytes

```
\:~2%[q\!|x]
```

This pushes a random number and outputs corresondingly to the random number.

Answer (score 0):

## TCL, 95 bytes

```
puts :q;puts [if [string match *!* [gets stdin]] {puts [lindex ":q! :x" [expr round(rand())]]}]
```

A simple and rather long solution in tcl...

Answer (score 0):

**Assembly 86Bytes** Linux System Calls

```
global _start
_start:
mov edx,4
mov ecx,g 
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4
int 0x80
g db ':q!',10
```

Answer (score 0):

## LOGO, <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
pr[:q]if 4<count rl[pr pick[:q! :x]]
```

Try it online at [Anarchy Golf Performance checker](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb).

## Explanation:

```
pr[:q]if 4<count rl[pr pick[:q! :x]]   Main program.
pr                                     Print
  [:q]                                 the list `[:q]` without delimiter `[]`
      if           [              ]    If...
         4<                            4 is less than...
           count                       the number of word in the...
                 rl                    ReadLine (from stdin),
                    pr                 print
                       pick            a random word picked from the list...
                           [:q! :x]    [:q! :x]
```

(because `E37@vimmachine: /var/override)` has 2 words, while `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)` has 10 words)

Comment: An explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5 (with -E flag), 35 bytes

```
say":q";<>=~l&&say qw(:q! :x)[$$%2]
```

Run this with `perl -E 'say":q";<>=~l&&say qw(:q! :x)[$$%2]'`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBmqmdoYP2/OLFSyapQydrGzrYuR00NyFUoLNewKlRUsKrQjFZRUTWK/f/f1djcSsEvX6G8KLMkVaE4My85VSEnsbhEITkjMS89VUEjMSVFQVGhJF8hvyy1qCgzJVUTAA)

Ungolfed:

```
say(":q");
if(<> =~ /l/){ #read a line and check if it contains 'l'
    @a=(":q!",":x");
    say($a[$$ % 2]); #print one element from array based on PID
}
```